# Saving Date and time in Parse backend

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have searched Parse blog to see if I can get the solution to this, but didn't get any satisfactory answer. So I though I will clearly ask the question here with all the details so anyone else stuck at similar situation will find it easy to work.

Need:
I have a departure and return text field which are updated using a single UIDatePicker. I want to save the selected dates in my Parse.com database. To which I can query and filter data. I also want to store local timezone in parse if possible. I am working with checking number of days but it was not relevant to this question so not including the code for that.

Success & Problem:
I am able to save correct date and time in String format , but when I try to save in NSDate format using the code below, I get wrong time.

For ex: my date selection and stored result in parse are as below:

Departure date:
Date Picker selection: 01/May/2015 01:00 AM +0530
Stored date in Parse: Apr 30, 2015, 19:30

Return Date:
Date Picker selection: 02/May/2015 01:00 AM +0530
Stored date in Parse: May 01, 2015, 19:30

//My code is as below:

```
@IBOutlet var dOfTravelText: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var returnDateText: UITextField!

 lazy var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm a Z"
    //        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .MediumStyle
    //        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
    return dateFormatter
    }()

    @IBAction func travelDatePicker(sender: UITextField) {

    datePickerView.minimumDate = NSDate()
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
    sender.inputView = datePickerView
    timeSelected = sender
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: "handleDatePicker:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.AllEvents)
}

// Date Picker target - Displaying date in textfield
func handleDatePicker(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    //var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    //dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    timeSelected.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    println("From Date \(dOfTravelText.text!)")
    println("To Date \(returnDateText.text!)")
}

// Submitting the dates to parse backend
    @IBAction func postBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
            let date = NSDate()
            let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitHour | .CalendarUnitMinute, fromDate: date)
            let dateMakerFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateMakerFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MMM/yyyy hh:mm a Z"

        let dD = dateMakerFormatter.dateFromString("\(dOfTravelText.text!)")!
        let departureD = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(dD, dateStyle: .MediumStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)
        println("From-------...\(departureD)")

        let rD = dateMakerFormatter.dateFromString("\(returnDateText.text!)")!
        let returnD = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(rD, dateStyle: .MediumStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)
        println("To-------\(returnD)")

        var userPost = PFObject(className:"UserPost")   
        userPost["departureDate"] = dD   // Works but has Wrong time
        userPost["rDate"] = rD   // Works but Wrong time
        userPost["travelDate"] = dOfTravelText.text // Works but it is stored in String format
        userPost["returnDate"] = returnDateText.text // Works but it is stored in string format
        userPost.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (success, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (success) {
                // The object has been saved.
                println("Saved")

            } else {
                // There was a problem, check error.description
                println("Error")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// Parse database column and type 
travelDate & returnDate are defined as of type "String"

departureDate & rDate are defined as Of type "Date"

Just for information: I am using
Platform - iOS Swift (xcode 6.3, swift 1.2)
Database backend = Parse.com

Comment: Parse stores the date in GMT. You could add an extra field to parse for storing the timezone and use that when reading the data to interpret the date in the zone it is referenced in.

Comment: @Volker Thank you for prompt reply. So what I did is, used postingLocZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().abbreviation! and saved it in my Parse backend. Later while retrieving, I used  dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "\(locationZone)"). This gives me the required results. But is this the right way to do this? Coz if the user changes his location, wont the posting date change (as NSTimeZone will also change)? I am kind of confused here. Would really help if you could give your views on this. Thanks :)

Comment: That is always a problem - you could check if the local time zone of the user and the saved timezone are different and ask the user for a resolution for example. Depending on your data it might be also okay to just change to local timezone without prompting.

Comment: hamm... thanks. Well, if I have to be sure. I will have to implement NSTimeZone for each location (posted zone, departure zone and return zone) and display the dates according to that. Like the user of the app should know what time he/she has to leave from X & start his return journey from Y location. This may work, but I am just wondering if this is the right way to do this? I will wait and see what other fellow SO experts have to say on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Parse stores the dates referenced to GMT, when you check them on parse or retrieve them, you may find this difference to your local timezone. In general dates are stored in GMT.

You can add an extra field in your Parse database and store the local timezone there. When retrieving data you can then use that information to interpret the date in the zone it is referenced in.

Depending on the type of data you store it might be okay to always interpret the date in the users local timezone, even when this has changed. You also could ask the user for a resolution if saved timezone and user timezone are different (so the user has moved).

Answer (score 0):

Setting up date pickers:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dDDatePicker: UIDatePicker!
@IBOutlet weak var rdDatePicker: UIDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setUpDatePickers()
}

func setUpDatePickers() {
    // Set start date
    dDDatePicker.date = Date()
    rdDatePicker.date = Date()
    // Set min and max date if you want
    dDDatePicker.maximumDate = minDepartDate
    rdDatePicker.maximumDate = minReturnDate
    dDDatePicker.minimumDate = maxDepartDate
    rdDatePicker.minimumDate = maxReturnDate
}
```

Saving dates to Parse:

```
func saveUserPost() {
    let dD = dDDatePicker.date
    let rd = rdDatePicker.date

    let userPost = PFObject(className: "UserPost")

    userPost["departureDate"] = dD   
    userPost["rDate"] = rD

    userPost.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
          (success, error) -> Void in
          if (success) {
              // The object has been saved.
              print("Saved")
          } else {
              // There was a problem, check error.description
              print("Error")
          }
     }
}
```

As mentioned date is saved in UTC I would use DateFormatter() to get it back to string in the correct time zone:

```
if let dD = userPost["departureDate"] as? Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let str = dateFormatter.string(from: dD)
    print("Depart date \(str)")
}
if let rD = userPost["rDate"] as? Date {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let str = dateFormatter.string(from: rD)
    print("Return date \(str)")
}
```

Use this link to set 'dateFormat' however you want:
https://nsdateformatter.com/

From my understanding dateFormatter will format to the devices current timeZone - Honestly I never tested it in different time zones but it works for EST - you can test and if not as mentioned you can also save the user time zone and then specify in date formatter like so

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "\(usertimeZone)")
```

Hope this helps!